# Let x,y be $x,y\in{\Bbb R}$. Suppose that $x^2+y^2=0$. Prove that $x =0$ and $y=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Okay so this is really obvious. I know that I can look at the cases if $x$ and $y$ are positive. If $x$ and $y$ are negative. Also, if they are both zero. I know that $x\ge 0$ and $y\ge 0$ then $x^2\ge 0$ and $y^2\ge 0$ then $x^2+y^2=0$. I don't know how to put this formally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or we can prove the contrapositive by showing that if $x\neq 0$ or $y\neq 0$, then $x^2+y^2\neq 0$.

To prove this, note that if   $$x\neq 0\mbox{ or }y\neq 0,$$ then 
$$x^2>0\mbox{ or }y^2>0,$$ which implies that 
$$x^2+y^2>0.$$

Answer (score 7):

$$0\le x^2\le x^2+y^2=0 \implies x^2=0 \implies x=0.$$
$$0\le y^2\le x^2+y^2=0 \implies y^2=0 \implies y=0.$$